# Magento - Cannot find which source files load .js in my <head> section

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, magento

My console gives me three 404 errors which are due to missing .js files loaded in my head section. I practically don't need them. But I want to stop getting 404s. It's really messing up my analytics and my SEO probably. 
Files are listed below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/skin/frontend/base/default/js/submenu/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/skin/frontend/base/default/js/submenu/jquery.noConflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/skin/frontend/base/default/js/submenu/jquery.accordion.min.js"></script>
```

So I noticed that some developer renamed the "submenu" folder to "-submenu", in order to avoid jquery conflicts. So I've tried to look for the files that load these .js's but I really don't have any clue where they are. I've spent hours searching for all local.xml, config.xml, page.xml, head.phtml, header.phtml files but still can't find anything.

Any clues to how can I easily trace what is loaded in my head section? Is there a "debugger" for this? Sorry, noob-in-coding designer

Comment: Thanks for this kaska. Solved it. no reputation to +1 you :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root directory of your magento you could do in a terminal

```
find . -iname "*jquery-1.10*"
find . -iname "*noConflict*"
```

This would find the files, but to remove them from being called:
You could also do a

```
grep -rnw . -e noConflict
```

and so on

To search within files, to find which layout xml or phtml file is adding them

Comment: Oh yes, you are a life saver. Found it and killed it. Thanks so much!